# python - create groups of tuples with tuples

Tags: python

Let's consider the following list of tuples:

```
[('AUD', 'M6A'),
 ('CHF', 'E7'),
 ('CHF', 'EUR'),
 ('CHF', 'M6E'),
 ('E7', 'CHF'),
 ('E7', 'EUR'),
 ('E7', 'M6E'),
 ('EMD', 'ES'),
 ('EMD', 'RTY'),
 ('ES', 'EMD'),
 ('ES', 'NQ'),
 ('EUR', 'CHF'),
 ('EUR', 'E7'),
 ('EUR', 'M6E'),
 ('GBP', 'M6B'),
 ('GF', 'LE'),
 ('LE', 'GF'),
 ('M6A', 'AUD'),
 ('M6B', 'GBP'),
 ('M6E', 'CHF'),
 ('M6E', 'E7'),
 ('M6E', 'EUR'),
 ('NIY', 'NKD'),
 ('NKD', 'NIY'),
 ('NQ', 'ES'),
 ('RTY', 'EMD')]
```

I would like to create from it a list of lists that clusters together the symbols that appear at least once together.

for instance `('CHF', 'EUR')` and `('E7', 'EUR')` would be merged into 1 list `['CHF', 'EUR', 'E7']` and so on.

Any idea how to achieve this?

---

For those who asked, here the loop idea to do that:

```
groups=[[]]
for item in li:
    for group in groups:
        if item[0] in group or item[1] in group:
            group.append(item)
        else:
            groups.append([item])
```

Horribly slow and ugly - actually it stunned my machine with memory usage.

The expected result is `[{'AUD', 'M6A'}, {'CHF', 'E7', 'EUR', 'M6E'}, {'EMD', 'ES', 'NQ', 'RTY'}, {'GBP', 'M6B'}, {'GF', 'LE'}, {'NIY', 'NKD'}]`

Comment: Occur together in the sense that they share at least one right element? What if you have `[(A,1),(B,1),(B,2),(C,2)]`. Should we then consider `[A,B,C]`?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Yes - they should be in separate sub-list only if they share no elements

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?

Comment: @AK47, I imagine because the OP hasn't shown any attempt to solve the problem. OP it looks like you are looking for disjoint set, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure.

Comment: @AK47 Wasn't me, but perhaps because the OP didn't try anything or show the expected output.

Comment: I know i could show i tried a loop but i suspect there is a better solution?

Comment: Where's your best good faith attempt to solve this? If you've tried something, you have to show it and use that code to make the question more specific.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Again i can show a loop doing that but it's ugly... I suspect there is a pandas or scipy way of doing that (clusters?) which i dont know. No need for you to resolve he problem, just a pointer would be great help.

Comment: @jimbasquiat If you can suffer through that ugliness their is a high probability that those who downvoted you will retract their votes, and someone offering you a pretty answer. I suppose it is your decision.

Comment: If that loop gave you the right answer, please take your code to code review. If it did not, please post it here. Also with the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for disjoint graphs, which you can use `networkx` to solve:

```
In []:
import networkx as nx
edges = [('AUD', 'M6A'), ('CHF', 'E7'), ('CHF', 'EUR'), ...]
g = nx.Graph(edges)
list(nx.connected_components(g))

Out[]:
[{'AUD', 'M6A'},
 {'CHF', 'E7', 'EUR', 'M6E'},
 {'EMD', 'ES', 'NQ', 'RTY'},
 {'GBP', 'M6B'},
 {'GF', 'LE'},
 {'NIY', 'NKD'}]
```

​If you want to avoid using `networkx` you can write it yourself reasonable efficiently (this should be `O(n)` to create the graph and `O(n)` to create the disjoint sets - which is overall `O(n)`) e.g.:

```
In []:
g = {}
for a, b in edges:
    g.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
    g.setdefault(b, []).append(a)

r = []
while g:
    s = set()
    q = [next(iter(g))]
    while q:
        k = q.pop()
        if k in s:
            continue
        s.add(k)
        for e in g.pop(k):
            q.append(e)
    r.append(s)
r

Out[]:
[{'AUD', 'M6A'},
 {'CHF', 'E7', 'EUR', 'M6E'},
 {'EMD', 'ES', 'NQ', 'RTY'},
 {'GBP', 'M6B'},
 {'GF', 'LE'},
 {'NIY', 'NKD'}]
```

Comment: AChampion: Ok thank you for this perfectly valid and concise solution. However if anyone had a solution not adding this extra dependency of networkx that would be good as well. A solution with pandas, numpy or scipy would be ideal. ANyway thx a lot already, will use that for now.

Answer (score -1):

How I understood the problem:

```
l =[('AUD', 'M6A'),('CHF', 'E7'), ('CHF', 'EUR'), ('CHF', 'M6E'), 
('E7', 'CHF'), ('E7', 'EUR'), ('E7', 'M6E'), ('EMD', 'ES'), ('EMD', 'RTY'),
('ES', 'EMD'), ('ES', 'NQ'), ('EUR', 'CHF'), ('EUR', 'E7'), ('EUR', 'M6E'),
('GBP', 'M6B'), ('GF', 'LE'), ('LE', 'GF'), ('M6A', 'AUD'), ('M6B', 'GBP'),
('M6E', 'CHF'), ('M6E', 'E7'), ('M6E', 'EUR'), ('NIY', 'NKD'), 
('NKD', 'NIY'), ('NQ', 'ES'),('RTY', 'EMD')]

s = set()
[s.add(tt) for t in l for tt in t]
print(s)
```

Oh sorry result is in s! My fault!

Comment: I like this approach but unfortuantely it is returning a list of `None`. The expected output is the one shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: hmm ok no the expected result was `[{'AUD', 'M6A'},
 {'CHF', 'E7', 'EUR', 'M6E'},
 {'EMD', 'ES', 'NQ', 'RTY'},
 {'GBP', 'M6B'},
 {'GF', 'LE'},
 {'NIY', 'NKD'}]` (as below)

Comment: Ok! Than its a graph problem not just merging.